# How to use translate pipe of ng2-translate to pass key for tanslation with out using .json file path

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ngx-translate

With **.json** the following is working fine:

```
    export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'src/app/test/', '.json');
    }
```

But I need how can I get translated data from service like CMS. How to pass two parameters to a translate pipe (key and sitemapid)? And how to write service to hit the server.

```
TranslateHttpLoader(http,'http://test.test.com/ts/content/Translations/{lang}/{sitemapid}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ngx-translate works great with json. You can use its pipe and services. In our project, on server side application startup, we fetch every messages in CMS and put them in a json file. Then, load that json file with ngx-translate.

However, If you need to access a link and get only single message, you should just use http.

```
http.get(`http://test.test.com/ts/content/Translations/${lang}/${sitemapid}`)
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.message = res);
```